# How to specify certAliasePassword in HttpsConnectorFactory?

Tags: java, jetty, dropwizard

I use dropwizard and jetty also I have keystore with password and alias with alias-password in this key store. How can I specify a password for alias which I can specify via this method 
`httpsConFactory.setCertAlias("my_alias);`

Comment: I have a suspicion that `keyManagerPassword` property is what you need but I'm not sure. https://www.dropwizard.io/en/latest/manual/configuration.html#https here we have `keyStorePassword`, `trustStorePassword` and the above password field. To find out more take a look at https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-jetty/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/jetty/HttpsConnectorFactory.java and then org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory. The second class is used by the first.

Comment: No, unfortunately dropwizard doesn't have full support of  JKS

Comment: Dropwizard is just providing a wrapper around Jetty's functionality. I don't know why Jetty's authors chose to not provide it. IMO the only reason to want a password per certificate alias is because there are several different certificates in the store. And this store is "provided" from somewhere. This doesn't seem a good idea to me.

Comment: @zloster totally agree with you

Comment: If the omitted part was only in the Dropwizard configuration code the solution would be easy: implement your own configuration and override. But involvement of the Jetty's code complicates the stuff.